# Add certain amount of white space find replace in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

I am playing around with c file editing, using eclipses find and replace.
I started out trying to find all cases, where a pointer to an element in our array of Frames was being initialised (Frame = struct used in the code) . I then changed the expression to make this array 2 dimensional.

```
find = (.*Frame\*|.*pFrame)(.*Frame.*=.*)(&Frames)(\[.*\])(\w*)

replace = $1$2&Frames\[group\]$4
```

so statements like this

```
Frame* thisFrame = &Frames[frame]
```

and this

```
pFrame myFrame = &Frames[i]
```

become this

```
Frame* thisFrame = &Frames[group][frame]
```

and this

```
pFrame myFrame = &Frames[group][i]
```

I now want to add white space to a certain line length, then add a comment. For example something like "// indexing Frames".

```
pFrame myFrame = &Frames[group][i]                       // indexing Frames
```

Basically I want to clean up the (\w*) bit. Any help appreciated.

P.S. I am a regex noob, so any suggested edits for a cleaner way of doing the find are welcome

Edit:
I would also like to edit the find to not include lines that start with //. I tried

```
([^//]+)(.*Frame\*|.*pFrame)(.*Frame.*=.*)(&Frames)(\[.*\])(\w*)
```

Comment: could i use range in someway ?

Comment: When trying to repro I get `Frame* thisFrame = &Frames&Frames[group]`, not `Frame* thisFrame = &Frames[group][frame]`. Are you sure you share the exact regexps?

Comment: @wiktor :) sorry I made an edit to the find when I was posting. There were 5 blocks but i didn't need the third. I then took it out of the find but forgot to update the replace to.  $1$2$3&Frames\[group\]$5

Comment: Try `^((?:(?!//).)*(?:Frame\*|pFrame))(.*Frame.*=.*)(&Frames)(\[.*\])(\w*)` --> `$1$2&Frames\[group\]$4                       // indexing Frames`

Comment: Cheers Wiktor. I will have to look at the addition to find to understand what you have done, but it stops the search finding the commented out lines. Nice :)

Comment: P.S. your search is way faster that the original (+points)

Comment: Yeah go ahead. That find was really helpful. On the replace I want my lines of code to be within say 90 characters and the comments to start at say the 91st character. something like find -> ^([^//]|.*)(//)(.*) then replace with something like -> $1(go to 91st character)//$3

Comment: Ok, I posted with some explanations. If you add more details to the question to make it clear what you are doing, I could help more.

Comment: gave you the tick :) cheers for the help

Comment: PS: It is a bit faster because you had two branches at the start that had the same beginning pattern `.*|.*`. This is highly inefficient, I placed the `.*` before the alternation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regards the spped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
^((?:(?!//).)*(?:Frame\*|pFrame))(.*Frame.*=.*)(&Frames)(\[.*\])(\w*)
```

to replace with `$1$2&Frames\[group\]$4                       // indexing Frames`.

*Explanations*:

- `^` - start of the line
- `((?:(?!//).)*(?:Frame\*|pFrame))` - Group 1 matching

  - `(?:(?!//).)*` - zero or more characters that are not a starting point for a `//` sequence
  - `(?:Frame\*|pFrame)` - `Frame*` or `pFrame`.
- `(.*Frame.*=.*)` - 0+ any chars up to the last `Frame`, 0+ any chars, `=` and again 0+ any chars
- `(&Frames)` - Literal `&Frames`
- `(\[.*\])` - Group 4 matching `[`, 0+ any chars and a `]`
- `(\w*)` - Group 5 matching 0+ word chars